# Making a C++ callable .lib or .dll file from a Mathematica notebook

Tags: interoperability, c++

MATLAB supports conversions of their function files into C++ callable libraries. I was wondering if the same feature is also available in *Mathemathica*?

If yes, can you please guide me where I can learn more about that feature.

Comment: Hi, you could have a look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10945/21), which is related.

Comment: Are you really the theoretical physicist? I didn't know that one of your professions is "web developer" so I'm a bit sceptic. Impersonating someone else might be offending or more.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can find something here.
http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CCompilerDriver/ref/CreateLibrary.html