# Compiling Visual Studio C++ to Run on Computers without Mathematica

Tags: mathematical-optimization, mathlink-or-wstp, c++

I have written a console application on Visual Studio C++ as below

```
#include <mathlink.h> //mathlink header
#include <stdio.h> //standard io header
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /* initialising variables */
    MLENV env = (MLENV)0;
    MLINK link = (MLINK)0;
    int errno;
    int packet;
    int input;

    /* initialises MathLink environemnt object */
    env = MLInitialize(0);

    /* links the program to the MathKernel */
    link = MLOpenString(env, "-linkmode launch -linkname 'C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\9.0\\math.exe'", &errno);
    MLActivate(link); //activates a MathLink connection with a mathlink program

    /* send 42+137 using the full form Plus[42, 137] */
    MLPutFunction(link, "Plus", 2); //integer 2 signifying 2 arguments passed to the MathLink program
    cout << "Enter the first integer: ";
    cin >> input;
    MLPutInteger(link, input); //puts the integer to the MathLink connection
    cout << "Enter the second integer: ";
    cin >> input;
    MLPutInteger(link, input); //puts the integer to the MathLink connection
    MLEndPacket(link); //indicates that current expression is complete and ready to be sent

    /* get packets until we find a ReturnPacket or error */
    while ((packet = MLNextPacket(link)) && packet != RETURNPKT) MLNewPacket(link);

    /* once the results is returned */
    if (MLError(link)) printf("\nError Has Occured!\n");    //if an error is returned
    else {                                                  //if an integer is returned
        int result;
        MLGetInteger(link, &result); //we know that the result is an integer in this case
        printf("\nResult: %d\n", result);
    }

    printf("\nPress Enter to Exit...");
    getchar(); //holds the console till users presses enter
    getchar(); //holds the console till users presses enter
    return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine. However, this uses MathLink, linking to math.exe. If I am to use the executable file of this code in a computer without Mathematica, it wouldnt work.

My solution explorer looks like:

[image]

Any advise on how to compile so that the file can be used in a computer without mathematica installed?

Comment: What you are asking for is not possible.  You cannot call Mathematica from your program on a computer where Mathematica is not installed.

Comment: @Szabolcs This has been asked before; would you help me find the duplicate(s)?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10920/12) and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39169/12) are related.

Comment: @Szabolcs strictly speaking I suppose that one could use MathLink to call a kernel running on a *different* computer. But, I agree, this probably isn't the use case the OP had in mind.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Good point.  Maybe things will change with the Wolfram Cloud http://www.wolframcloud.com/ (about which I know nothing except this URL).