# Executable notebooks

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, dialog-window

Last week I made a code, where I use dialogboxes do create a graphic interface. I want this code to be available to any person that might have or not Mathematica. Is there a way to turn this notebook into an executable file? Or at least be able to simply click in the file and readily evaluate the notebook?
I've heard about cfd files, but I still don't understand their advantage over notebooks very well and I'm aware I shouldn't be mistaking them for executable files.
This is the code in its early stages, from last week:

```
CreateDialog[
  DynamicModule[{inputs, outputs, req1, req2, req3, req4, reqa, reqb, 
    reqc, reqd, r1, r2, r3, r4, ra, rb, rc, rd, sol, sol1, sol2, sol3,
     sol4, sola, solb, solc, sold, eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eqa, eqb, eqc, 
    eqd},

   inputs = 
    MapThread[
     Row[{"Equivalent MS", #1, ": ", 
        InputField[Dynamic@#2, Number, 
         FieldSize -> {5, 1}]}] &, {{"1", "2", "3", "4", "A", "B", 
       "C", "D"}, {req1, req2, req3, req4, reqa, reqb, reqc, reqd}}];

   outputs =
    MapThread[
     Row[{"        MS", #1, ": ",
        Dynamic@
         Pane[Dynamic@#2, 100, BaseStyle -> {Background -> White}, 
          FrameMargins -> 4]}] &, {{"1", "2", "3", "4", "A", "B", "C",
        "D"}, {sol1, sol2, sol3, sol4, sola, solb, solc, sold}}
     ];

   sum = req1 = 
     req2 = req3 = 
       req4 = reqa = 
         reqb = reqc = 
           reqd = sol1 = 
             sol2 = sol3 = sol4 = sola = solb = solc = sold = 0;

   Column[{Row[{Column[Join[inputs, {}]

        ],
       Column[outputs]

       }],
     Row[{Button["Reset", 
        req1 = req2 = 
          req3 = req4 = 
            reqa = reqb = 
              reqc = reqd = 
                sol1 = sol2 = 
                  sol3 = sol4 = sola = solb = solc = sold = 0],

       Button["Compute",
        If[
         req1 == 0 || req2 == 0 || req3 == 0 || req4 == 0 || 
          reqa == 0 || reqb == 0 || reqc == 0 || 
          reqd == 0, {sol1 = 
           sol2 = sol3 = sol4 = sola = solb = solc = sold = 0}, {


          eq1 = (r1*(((r3 + 
                    r4)*(((ra + rb)*(rc + rd))/(ra + rb + rc + 
                    rd)))/(r3 + 
                    r4 + (((ra + rb)*(rc + rd))/(ra + rb + rc + 
                    rd))) + 
                 r2))/(r1 + (((r3 + 
                    r4)*(((ra + rb)*(rc + rd))/(ra + rb + rc + 
                    rd)))/(r3 + 
                   r4 + ((ra + rb)*(rc + rd))/(ra + rb + rc + rd))) + 
               r2) == req1;

          eq2 = (r2*(((r3 + 
                    r4)*(((ra + rb)*(rc + rd))/(ra + rb + rc + 
                    rd)))/(r3 + 
                    r4 + (((ra + rb)*(rc + rd))/(ra + rb + rc + 
                    rd))) + 
                 r1))/(r2 + (((r3 + 
                    r4)*(((ra + rb)*(rc + rd))/(ra + rb + rc + 
                    rd)))/(r3 + 
                   r4 + ((ra + rb)*(rc + rd))/(ra + rb + rc + rd))) + 
               r1) == req2;

          eq3 = (r3*(((r1 + 
                    r2)*(((ra + rb)*(rc + rd))/(ra + rb + rc + 
                    rd)))/(r1 + 
                    r2 + (((ra + rb)*(rc + rd))/(ra + rb + rc + 
                    rd))) + 
                 r4))/(r3 + (((r1 + 
                    r2)*(((ra + rb)*(rc + rd))/(ra + rb + rc + 
                    rd)))/(r1 + 
                   r2 + ((ra + rb)*(rc + rd))/(ra + rb + rc + rd))) + 
               r4) == req3;

          eq4 = (r4*(((r1 + 
                    r2)*(((ra + rb)*(rc + rd))/(ra + rb + rc + 
                    rd)))/(r1 + 
                    r2 + (((ra + rb)*(rc + rd))/(ra + rb + rc + 
                    rd))) + 
                 r3))/(r4 + (((r1 + 
                    r2)*(((ra + rb)*(rc + rd))/(ra + rb + rc + 
                    rd)))/(r1 + 
                   r2 + ((ra + rb)*(rc + rd))/(ra + rb + rc + rd))) + 
               r3) == req4;

          eqa = (ra*(((rc + 
                    rd)*(((r1 + r2)*(r3 + r4))/(r1 + r2 + r3 + 
                    r4)))/(rc + 
                    rd + (((r1 + r2)*(r3 + r4))/(r1 + r2 + r3 + 
                    r4))) + 
                 rb))/(ra + (((rc + 
                    rd)*(((r1 + r2)*(r3 + r4))/(ra + rb + rc + 
                    rd)))/(rc + 
                   rd + ((r1 + r2)*(r3 + r4))/(r1 + r2 + r3 + r4))) + 
               rb) == reqa;

          eqb = (rb*(((rc + 
                    rd)*(((r1 + r2)*(r3 + r4))/(r1 + r2 + r3 + 
                    r4)))/(rc + 
                    rd + (((r1 + r2)*(r3 + r4))/(r1 + r2 + r3 + 
                    r4))) + 
                 ra))/(rb + (((rc + 
                    rd)*(((r1 + r2)*(r3 + r4))/(ra + rb + rc + 
                    rd)))/(rc + 
                   rd + ((r1 + r2)*(r3 + r4))/(r1 + r2 + r3 + r4))) + 
               ra) == reqb;

          eqc = (rc*(((ra + 
                    rb)*(((r1 + r2)*(r3 + r4))/(r1 + r2 + r3 + 
                    r4)))/(ra + 
                    rb + (((r1 + r2)*(r3 + r4))/(r1 + r2 + r3 + 
                    r4))) + 
                 rd))/(rc + (((ra + 
                    rb)*(((r1 + r2)*(r3 + r4))/(ra + rb + rc + 
                    rd)))/(ra + 
                   rb + ((r1 + r2)*(r3 + r4))/(r1 + r2 + r3 + r4))) + 
               rd) == reqc;

          eqd = (rd*(((ra + 
                    rb)*(((r1 + r2)*(r3 + r4))/(r1 + r2 + r3 + 
                    r4)))/(ra + 
                    rb + (((r1 + r2)*(r3 + r4))/(r1 + r2 + r3 + 
                    r4))) + 
                 rc))/(rd + (((ra + 
                    rb)*(((r1 + r2)*(r3 + r4))/(ra + rb + rc + 
                    rd)))/(ra + 
                   rb + ((r1 + r2)*(r3 + r4))/(r1 + r2 + r3 + r4))) + 
               rc) == reqd;


          sol = FindRoot[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eqa, eqb, eqc, 
             eqd}, {{r1, 1}, {r2, 1}, {r3, 1}, {r4, 1}, {ra, 1}, {rb, 
              1}, {rc, 1}, {rd, 1}}],
          sol1 = sol[[1, 2]], sol2 = sol[[2, 2]], sol3 = sol[[3, 2]], 
          sol4 = sol[[4, 2]], sola = sol[[5, 2]], solb = sol[[6, 2]], 
          solc = sol[[7, 2]], sold = sol[[8, 2]]



          }]],
       CancelButton[], DefaultButton[]}]

     }]
   ],
  WindowTitle -> "Wheatstone Bridges"
  ];
```

Comment: A CDF file can be opened using the free [CDF player](https://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/) than anyone can download. (But it's a pretty big download.)  A notebook can only be opened with Mathematica (and a Mathematica license costs money).  There is no way to create a small executable that works without additional software. The closest you can come is making a CDF that works with software that is free of charge.

Comment: And there's of course the Wolfram Cloud stuff which avoids the whole separate software download issue. But then it is *you* (not your users) who needs to pay once the free amount of views for the webpage have been exceeded.

Comment: See: [10945](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10945/5478), [3964](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3964/5478), [14022](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14022/5478),http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/faq/ . Is there anything that those topics do not cover?