# Making Standalone executable out of any mathematica program

Tags: scripting, education

Is it possible to make an executable file out of any mathematica program so that It can be run on any windows computer not having the mathematica.

In case of FORTRAN (on windows), it is possible to do the same.

Any suggestions are most welcomed.

Comment: You can check: https://www.wolfram.com/player/ . In addition to the free version, there is a Pro version available as well. Specific to your query: exe files cannot be created.

Comment: @syed, yes, looks like that exe files cannot be created in matheamtica

Comment: Strongly related, if not duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39169/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37888/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10920/1871